# Migration python 2 to 3: types.FileType

Tags: python, file, io

When migrating from Python 2 to Python 3 using `2to3`, the import of `types.FileType` has not been adapted.

Is it appropriate to check with `isinstance()` for `io.TextIOWrapper` and `io.StringIO` in order to distinguish between the two cases?

Or, is there a more modern pythonic way to deal with that?

Comment: Why do you care about that distinction?

Comment: Because a StringIO does usually not have a `.name` associated with it. The error reporting would be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach here is [EAFP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Exceptions): try to read the `name` attribute (which might usefully exist, after all, on any sort of file-like stream wrapper) and fall back to other behavior on `AttributeError`.  If all you need is a default value, use `getattr(f,'name',default)`; `default` can be `"<unknown>"` or something of a different type (like `None`) that unambiguously preserves the information as to whether the attribute was present (as a string).